# Get time every 1 second javascript

Tags: javascript, date, setinterval

I have created a script that gets executed every 1 second and outputs the current hour,min and seconds in a span like this:

```js
setInterval(()=>{
    let date = new Date();
    let time = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
    document.getElementById('foo').innerText = time;
}, 1000);
```

```html
Time :<span id ='foo'>00:00:00</span>
```

As you can see every 1 second I am creating a new `Date` object.
Is there any better way to achieve this without having to recreate the `Date` object every 1 second?

Comment: Dont think so ..

Comment: Better way... how?  Define "better".  Why do you want to avoid creating a new date object?

Comment: I think... it's not a problem.

Comment: For performance reasons I can't see why you'd need to attempt to shave off even a millisecond of time when you have another *thousand* before anything else happens.

Comment: This is totally a non–issue. Date objects are extremely simple, they are just a time value and a bunch of inherited methods. Setting *innerHTML* likely uses vastly more resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just increment the seconds of an existing `Date` object:

```
let date = new Date();

setInterval(() => {
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);

    let time = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
    document.getElementById('foo').innerText = time;
}, 1000);
```

The question is, however,

1. how much this will actually gain you in performance; and
2. how exact the timing of the execution of the intervalled method is, and how much drift there would be over time between your calculated date and the actual date. You might want to resynchronize again, e.g. every hour or so.

Comment: Except that *setInterval* doesn't run at exactly the specified interval, so the clock will slowly drift. Whether this is "better" or not is open to dispute. Also unclear why setting seconds to a new value uses fewer resources than just creating a new Date.

Comment: @RobG Aren't you just repeating everything I said in the second half of my answer?

Comment: While it's an alternative, there is no indication of "better", so not really an answer. :-(